# How to Validate "Digit" Range on handle validation in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, regex, validation

I am trying to **validate input data** while entered the data. Where, I want to validate Input data in digit and **Data Format is:** 000-000-000. Where, also I have to validate each **000 value range in between (000-255)** only.

> Like: 000-000-000 to 255-255-255.

```
onHandleValidation = (event, submitted) =>
    {
        let fields = this.state.formFields;
        let errors = this.state.formErrors;
        let field = (event)? event.target.name: "";
        let Validate = true;

if (field === 'digit' || submitted) {
            if(fields.digit=== ""){
                errors["digit"] = "This field is required";
                Validate = false;
            } else {
                if(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/.test(fields.digit) === false){
                    errors['digit'] = "digit Format 000-000-0000 Required";
                    Validate = false;
                }
            }
        }

        this.setState({formErrors: errors, formValid: formValid});
        return Validate;
    }
```

Validation for **Format: 000-000-000** is done. For second Validation, I am trying, but, Not find any solution yet.

For Any Help. **Thank You!**

Comment: I'm not gonna say it's not possible, but I think the regex will look just like gibberish and not quite readable. Validating the second criteria should be done with some JS. It's short and concise

Comment: @dshung1997 Why do you say it's not possible? Yes, it will look like gibberish but any sufficiently useful regex looks like gibberish. If it doesn't look like gibberish then either your requirement is super simple or you've fatally overlooked the requirements.

Comment: @bharti You can only accept one answer. There's no need to bounce around. Select the one that helped you the most or ended up using. If you like my answer then an upvote is also appreciated.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't say it's not possible my friend. Just look at the regex. It would cost you more than a few lines of JS if you'll need to maintain or change it. But you're sure that the requirement will never change, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be how to do it in pure regex

```
^(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])-(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])-(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QzpxmF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just a basic idea of how to do this

```js
const valid = "000-000-000";
const valid2 = "255-255-255";
const valid3 = "123-200-067";
const invalid1 = "000-000-0001";
const invalid2 = "000-0001";
const invalid3 = "000-000-300";

const validate = (digits) => {
  const allDigits = digits.split("-");
  console.log(allDigits);

  // return false if not enough parts
  if (allDigits.length !== 3) {
    console.log("not enough parts");
    return false;
  }

  // validate length of parts
  const validLengths = allDigits.every((digit) => digit.length === 3);
  // return false if one length is violated
  if (!validLengths) {
    console.log("at least one part has an incorrect length");
    return false;
  }

  // validate maximum and minimum
  const inRange = allDigits.every((digit) => digit >= 0 && digit <= 256);

  if (!inRange) {
    console.log("at least one is out of range");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

console.log("validate", valid, validate(valid));
console.log("validate", valid2, validate(valid2));
console.log("validate", valid3, validate(valid3));
console.log("validate", invalid1, validate(invalid1));
console.log("validate", invalid2, validate(invalid2));
console.log("validate", invalid3, validate(invalid3));
```

[image: console log]

I am not the regex guru, so someone else might add a regex solution

Comment: Thank You, For your the basic idea. I have tried this, it's also working for me. Thank You!